# I have a design for powering four motors, could someone verify that it will work as I planned?

Tags: power-supply, brushless-dc-motor

**My question:**

This is a simple design that I have created using everything that I know about electronics so far. Is there anything missing in my design or are there any concepts which I have misunderstood ?

**My design:**

*Preliminary stage:*

An AC to DC adaptor that was originally used to power a phone was repurposed as a power-supply for an ESC which controls a BLDC motor. This power supply was used as a Lipo battery was not available. This adaptor was able to power this motor to a satisfactory level. The setup was adapted from a youtube video (link is at the bottom).
[image]

*Proposed design*

Since the adaptor worked with one motor, it will now be used with four. Although this would drastically reduce the current used by each motor, this should not matter that much as no load is being applied to the motor.

This adaptor will be connected in parallel to 4 electronic speed controllers which in turn power four 1000KV BLDC motors. The adaptor takes in a 220 - 240V 100mA current at 50/60Hz from the power socket in the wall and outputs a 5.5V DC current at 500mA.

Since the loads are connected in parallel they will all receive the supply voltage and equally share the current provided therefore, each motor will receive 125mA current at 5.5V. Since rpm = KV * volts therefore, the maximum rpm of each motor will be 5500rpm. No load will be applied to the motors.

I checked the data-sheet for the motor(link is here: https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/26/BLDC_A2212_13T.pdf) but I couldn't find any information on the minimum current needed for the motor to spin at 5500rpm. The data-sheet did say that the No load current was 0.5A but apparently this was only true if the voltage was 10V.

**Why am I using this design or asking these questions?**

I made this design so that I could test whether I understood the principles behind choosing a power supply for my motors. If the logic that I used above is correct then I can figure out how heavy my drone will be -> how much lift force each motor needs to generate -> how much current each motor will draw -> how many mAh my lipo battery will need to be. So this design is essential for any work that I plan to do in the future.

If the logic is incorrect then I was hoping that someone could point out where I was going wrong or provide resources which could help me improve my understanding.

**Links to equipment:**

Motors:
https://www.amazon.com.au/QWinOut-Brushless-Outrunner-Multi-Copter-Quadcopter/dp/B07CVDHQKS

ESC:
https://qwinout.com/products/qwinout-2-4s-30a-rc-brushless-esc-simonk-firmware-electric-speed-controller-with-5v-3a-bec-for-2-to-4s-lipo-battery-diy-multicopter-quadcopter

Layout:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOQk8SJso6Q
Timestamp: 9:24

Comment: Can you measure the actual current draw for the single motor on 5.5 V? It will probably be in the order of 250-300 mA. With four motors in parallel, it should be about 1200 mA, which is beyond the capacity of the charger. I don't see why you need to try this. A 3S LiPo pack will be about 12V. You should be able to find a 12 V supply to use while experimenting and before using a battery.

Comment: Hello @PstechPaul, I cannot measure the current draw because I do not have a multi-meter yet. How did you figure out that the current draw for each motor is 250-300mA? I thought the current draw would be the current supply from the motor / 4?

Comment: From your numbers, each motor will probably want to draw 250 - 300 mA independent of any other motors or other loads.  If the supply cannot supply the required total current, the supply may overheat and be damaged, or may reduce its output voltage to keep the total current within its limits. (or other Bad Things may happen)

Comment: I see now thankyou Peter, I will definitely use a power supply that can provide more current. How did you know that the motor will draw 250 - 300mA, my calculations placed that at 125mA per motor? I just want to know for future reference.

Comment: You said the no-load current of the motor on a 10 volt supply was 500 mA - we made a wild guess that it would draw half the current when supplied with half the voltage, based on Ohm's Law - but Ohm's Law doesn't necessarily apply to motors due to back-EMF from the motor...

Comment: That makes sense now. thanks Peter.